# What is the easiest way to record an audio stream at a certain time on a pc?

Tags: windows, recording, audio-streaming

What is the easiest way to record an audio stream at a certain time on a pc, using Windows? I need to be able to schedule it to start recording at for example 22:00 and stop at 00:00.

Comment: Added it probably while you were asking. Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy...
You have to use a dos command:

SoundRecorder /FILE filename.filetype /DURATION hhhh:mm:ss

If you add it to a batch file and schedule its running the problem is solved :)

Right now I'm on a rush but if you need further info to accomplish each step just ask

Comment: Do you have an example of a program which does this and accepts streams?

Comment: I've used a silly audio minijack going out from my output to my input :)

Which kind of stream should you record? In that case a specific app would probably do better than my idea.

Comment: Can you use your solution to record a stream by passing a URL?

Comment: You can use it to record all the sounds produced by your computer so if your computer is playing at the right time the url it'll record it.

I'd suggest you to try @Michiel Borkent solution to this question: looks simple and works probably better :)

Answer (score 2):

I found this free program which does exactly what I want:

- it records directly to mp3
- I can schedule when it will begin and stop recording

I just open the stream in for example iTunes and the program records "what you hear", so it doesn't read the stream directly, but that's ok with me.

http://www.mp3mymp3.com/